# How to set ImageView width in android ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, imageview, android-imageview, picasso

## ListVeiw Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="6dip">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:background="#F8F8F6"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false" />
.....
.....
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using `picasso` for the transformation (Transformation is related to add some new image on this `ImageView`).

## ListView Adapter code

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (null == convertView) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);
    }

    ImageTransform imageTransformation = new ImageTransform(context);


    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


    Picasso
            .with(context)
            .load("http://i.imgur.com/rFLNqWI.jpg")
            .transform(imageTransformation)
            .into(imageView);
 return convertview;
}
```

## code in ImageTransformation

```
 @Override
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap bitmap) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    synchronized (ImageTransform.class) {
        if(bitmap == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Bitmap resultBitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(), true);
        Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_heart);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setTextSize(50);
        paint.setShadowLayer(2.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, Color.BLACK);

        canvas.drawText("$250", 10, 500, paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapImage, 900, 20, null);
        bitmap.recycle();
        return resultBitmap;
    }
```

According to above I can see following `listView`

## Questions

- How to make size fixed of every image whether it is scaled properly or not because in future I will use best layout?
- How to increase the width of image. So that the image width will cover whole part of the screen?
- Whenever I am in `landscape` mode distortion take place. How to avoid it?

[image]

Comment: try  `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` in your image view XML , it will even stretch images to fit the imageView and it looks better in image lists

Comment: in landscape mode ,redefine your UI dedicatedly for landscape, a good idea is to display two images side-by-side to which will address two things: 
 ->utilization of space
 ->Reasonably width scaled images without loss os quality due to too much width scaling/stretching.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all image to be specific size use `.resize()` function provided by Picasso library and use `.centerCrop()` to fit the image nicely

```
Picasso.with(context)
 .load("http://i.imgur.com/rFLNqWI.jpg")
 .resize(100, 100) //Specify whatever size you want
 .centerCrop()
 .transform(imageTransformation)
 .into(imageView)
```

Comment: When I am using resize(size, size),  It is not loading any images. Check out the screenshot  http://i.imgur.com/Vb9EjMQ.png

Comment: Did you try with some other image link,